# Text Recognizer from image to find the date

Tags: android, date, text-recognition

In my app I am trying to find the date from image using Text Recognizer. But in image the date can be in any format such as:

dd/mm/yyyy, dd-mm-yyyy, dd mm yyyy, dd mmm yyyy, dd-mmm-yyyy, dd/mmm/yyyy etc.

Dependencies:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:18.0.0"
```

Code:

```
TextRecognizer mText = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationCOntext()).build();
if(mText.isOperational()) {
   readText(bitmap,mtext);
}

private void readText(Bitmap bitmap, TextRecognizer mTextRecognizer) {
   if(bitmap != null) {
      Frame mframe = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
      SparseArray<TextBlock> mTextBlockSparseArray = mTextRecognizer.detect(mframe);
      StringBuilder mStringBuffer = new StringBuilder();

      
   }
}
```

How to get the **DATE** from the image?

Answer (score 0):

### String.replaceFirst() and java.time through ThreeTenABP

There are some different ways to go about it. I present a kind of mixed approach: I am using a regular expression for the different possible delimiters, which validates that both delimiters (after day and after month) are the same. Next I am using optional parts in the format pattern string to handle month as either abbreviation (`Jan`) or number (`01`).

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-[MMM][MM]-uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);

    String[] inputs = { "02/01/2020", "04-01-2020", "07 01 2020",
            "09 Jan 2020", "13-Jan-2020", "17/Jan/2020" };

    for (String input : inputs) {
        String withHyphens = input.replaceFirst("([/ ])(.*)\\1", "-$2-");
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(withHyphens, dateFormatter);
        System.out.format("%11s was parsed into %s%n", input, date);
    }
```

Output from this smippet is:

> ```
>  02/01/2020 was parsed into 2020-01-02
>  04-01-2020 was parsed into 2020-01-04
>  07 01 2020 was parsed into 2020-01-07
> 09 Jan 2020 was parsed into 2020-01-09
> 13-Jan-2020 was parsed into 2020-01-13
> 17/Jan/2020 was parsed into 2020-01-17
> ```

If you prefer, you may also use optional parts in the format pattern string for everything. Then your format pattern may look like `dd[/][-][ ][MMM][MM][/][-][ ]uuuu`. It gives more lenient validation, but is more consistent and shorter.

I am using the backport of java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.